# Can Threshold auctions be used to prevent the free rider problem in public goods?

Tags: public-goods, free-riding, commons

I've been thinking about free-rider problems in public goods.

Basically, the issue is that a public good may have a cost of production associated with it (say for example, knowledge. Knowledge, once produced, is easy to spread, see the internet, but producing it has a cost).

So the question I've been wondering is: how can public goods be financed in a self-organized manner? Typically the solution is presented as either property rights (and therefore paywalls) or state coercion. But ever since reading Elinor Ostrom I've become fascinated by other potential solutions.

As such, I was doing some reading and came across this article: https://masterwp.com/saving-the-future-and-solving-the-free-rider-problem/

The basic premise is that we can use a "threshold auction" to prevent the free rider problem.

To summarize,
The free rider problem is basically when there is a public good that could be produced but because no one can prevent access to it, then why would I pay for its production? If everyone thinks like that, nothing gets produced and we're all worse off.

I've modified the threshold auction from the article so that it works like this:
A public good has a set cost of production. That production cost needs to be met. Now, the free-rider problem is only a problem if everyone thinks that they can benefit without paying. A threshold auction works by setting a fixed date and saying "if the cost of production hasn't been met, this good will not be produced". This means that free riders are effectively forced into a game of chicken, where each one is trying to pay as little as possible before the date. They may not be able to free ride because the good may not be produced. If the money is raised in time, the good gets produced. If not it doesn't.

So like, as an example, a search engine run without ads and freely open to the public can say: "We need $x to pay our worker wages and server hosting fees. If we don't get it by Friday next week we cannot host our site and it will go down".

Is this a viable solution? It may not be 100% functional all the time, but you would expect it to converge right? Where the folks with the greatest utility are the least likely to be willing to let it not be produced?

Now this isn't guaranteed to work, and it can result in a market failure, but I do think that over time, if the utility of a good is high enough, people will generally have a strong incentive to see that it is produced.